# flex-direction row not behaving as row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox grid that I'm using for some cards, however the cards when given the css property of `flex-direction: row;` will not actually behave as a row, but instead, will behave as column. I tried marking it as !important, however, it still will not behave as row. I would like each element to fit decently before going to a second line.

I've read this [article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) many times trying to find out why it isn't behaving like I want to, but I haven't been able to hit the deal. Any idea why this is happening?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yisera/qtv5h5eb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your elements *are* behaving as a row. Each item is just so wide that it's wrapping around (`flex-wrap`), and you're getting what *looks like* a column.

Reducing the width of the `.wall-panel`s puts them back in a row-like formation.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/qtv5h5eb/2/

Comment: this works, however, how can I make them go full 100% width? At this moment, they're taking only what it seems to be 1200px of the container

Comment: @codeninja `flex-grow`. Remove margin. Or, play with the `width` setting.